# how can i take a screen shot of current mobile screen View through Service (background process) Android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programatically take a screenshot on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)

I am New at Android My Question is that How can i take screen shots of current Mobile Screen View through Service. can anybody help me????

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that you will need a rooted device, also that it will be hard if not impossible since it will be nos safe at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Comment: @RotaryHeart you are 100% wrong regarding Rooted device :)

Comment: This has been asked a bazillion times.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=capture+screen+shot+android